# How to remove cloned git repo from a second git repo?

Tags: git, git-submodules

I accidentally added a cloned git repository to a working copy clone of my repository, and pushed the changes to my remote. I did not use git submodule to do that, but rather did something like "git add somedir.git".

Now whenever I clone my repo, I get an empty "somedir.git" directory. I cannot do a "git rm -r somedir", because git complains "somedir.git is a directory".

How can I get rid of this directory or convert it into a proper submodule? The directory is completely empty after cloning, not even a .git/ folder in there.

Comment: have you tried to simply `rm -rf somedir.git`, and then commit its deletion?

Comment: cool, added as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Git fails at deleting the directory because it is empty, it has always been tricky with empty directory (BTW it's not clear to me why cloning the repo gives you this empty directory!)

Simply `rm -rf somedir.git` and commit its deletion.